# After login, my login page is displayed with my dashboard

Tags: angular, typescript

In the login page, I enter my username -> `test1`

[first - step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UsVq.png)

After the connection, I have the login page and the dashboard displayed at the same time.

[second - step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cps5M.png)

The login page should disappear after login.

***app.component.html***

```
<app-login></app-login>

<app-dashboard-layout [configuration]="configuration">
  <div container="sidePanel" *ngIf="currentUser">
    <app-navigation-side-panel [links]="links"></app-navigation-side-panel>
  </div>
  <div container="navigationBar" *ngIf="currentUser">
    <app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
  </div>
  <div container="mainContent">
    <div *ngIf="currentUser">
      <a style="color: black" (click)="logout()">Logout </a>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-dashboard-layout>
```

I think the problem is below:

```
<app-login></app-login>
```

Here is a simulation -> [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ksxcgt?file=src/app/app.component.html)

I don't know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put `<app-login></app-login>` in app.component.html file.
Here is a right code.

```
    <app-dashboard-layout [configuration]="configuration" *ngIf="currentUser">
  <div container="sidePanel">
    <app-navigation-side-panel [links]="links"></app-navigation-side-panel>
  </div>
  <div container="navigationBar" *ngIf="currentUser">
    <app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
  </div>
  <div container="mainContent">
    <div>
      <a style="color: black" (click)="logout()">Logout </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</app-dashboard-layout>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Ah Yesss! Thank you. But, why my header from my login page isn' t to width:100% ?

Comment: Because current login page uses dashboard-layout. Normally, login page uses a different layout something like empty-layout.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, where login page called dashboard-layout, please? I don't really see the problem. :-(

Comment: Because your <router-outlet></router-outlet> is inside dashboard-layout. I updated my code above. It will simply fix your problem. Please accept my answer if it was helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Thank so much for your help. It works.. It's just weird that the title of the `home` page has disappeared, but I think that's another problem?